# How prevent asp:TreeNode indent spacing as parent node?

Tags: webforms

In `asp:TreeView` is the very last node, the `asp:TreeNode` w/ the `Text="Inspections"`, how do you prevent tab indent from showing when it is only a clickable parent node & never will have child nodes?  Here's the code & the picture of what I got instead.

```
   <asp:TreeView ID="treeReports" runat="server" CssClass="p-3"
       OnSelectedNodeChanged="treeReports_SelectedNodeChanged"
       NodeStyle-CssClass="treeNode"
       RootNodeStyle-CssClass="rootNode"
       ExpandImageUrl="~/Content/icons/plus-solid.png"
       CollapseImageUrl="~/Content/icons/minus-solid.png"
       LeafNodeStyle-ImageUrl="~/Content/icons/document.png"
       SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="treeSelectedNode"
       ViewStateMode="Enabled"
       LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="leafNode">
       <Nodes>
           <asp:TreeNode Text="Inventory" SelectAction="Expand">
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Manager's Inventory" Value="managerInventory" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Purchase" Value="inventoryPurchase" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Salesperson Inventory" Value="salespersonInventory" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Accounts Receivable" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Age Analysis" Value="arAgeAnalysis" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Balance" Value="arBalance" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Cash Intake" Value="arCashIntake" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Delinquency" Value="arDelinquency" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Earned/Unearned" Value="arEarnedUnearned" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="IRS Form 1099" Value="arIRS1099" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Recency" Value="arRecency" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Unpaid Down Payments" Value="arUnpaidDownPayments" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Sales" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Commission" Value="salesCommission" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Credit Apps" Value="salesCreditApplications" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Detail" Value="detailSales" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Tax" Value="salesTax" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Unpaid Trade Liens" Value="salesUnpaidTradeLiens" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Insurance" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Expiration/Cancellation" Value="insuranceExpirationCancellation" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Research" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Customer" Value="customerResearch" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Management" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Deferment" Value="managementDeferment" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Past Payment" Value="managementPastPayment" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Refinance" Value="managementRefinance" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Repo/CHG Off" Value="managementRepoCHGOff" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Static Pool" Value="managementStaticPool" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Finance" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Proceed" Value="financeProceed" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Misc" SelectAction="Expand">
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Bankruptcy" Value="bankruptcy" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Impound" Value="impound" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="No Pay" Value="noPay" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Out for Repo" Value="outForRepo" />
                   <asp:TreeNode Text="Secured Units" Value="securedUnits" />
               </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Text="Inspections" Value="inspectionReports">
               </asp:TreeNode>
           </Nodes>
       </asp:TreeView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem in the markup. The Manager's Inventory's opening tag is closed but has child nodes.

Comment: It's not that.  It wasn't indent correctly in the post.  Oh well